# Can Unit tests test methods NOT declared in the .h file?

Tags: ios, unit-testing

Can Unit tests test methods NOT declared in the .h file?

If unit tests can't, should I declare all methods in the .h file just for unit tests? Is this unproductive or worth it?

Comment: There are many questions about unit testing private methods with answers http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=unit+testing+private+methods

Answer (score 4):

What I do when I want to test what would otherwise be private methods, is define a category with the method definitions for testing.  By putting the category in a separate file you maintain the appearance of private methods.  You can still have the implementation in the main .m file, no need to do anything different there.

There are other ways to handle it, like putting them in the main .h file, or defining the category in the test implementations themselves, but they all seem at least a little dirty to me.  I really like my interface files to reflect the public interface and keep my privates private.

Comment: I'll up vote this. I love having a category named Private on all my classes for called private methods in tests. However, its worth noting that I never test private methods. I test public methods for their documented behavior and call private methods as necessary to do so.

Comment: @RyanPoolos that's probably a better way of stating it.